# How to find the equations of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given $V$ vector space, and $W$ a subspace of $V$.
How can I get the equations that describe $W$ if I'm only given its basis?

I would like to know the logic behind it rather than just the procedure or the direct answer

Comment: Given a basis $b_1,...,b_d$ then $W = \{ \sum_k x_k b_k \}_x$ where the $x_k$ take any scalar values.

Comment: Yes, but what I want to know its for example if W $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^4$ I have equations like $x+y-2z=0$. How can I find those ones if I'm only given the basis of the subspaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is that $W$ is described by saying it's precisely the set of vectors orthogonal to $W^\perp$, the orthogonal complement. We find a basis for $W^\perp$ by solving $Ax=0$, where the basis vectors for $W$ are the *row vectors* of $A$. [To say $x$ solves $Ax=0$ is to say precisely that $x$ is orthogonal to the rows of $A$, and hence to any linear combination of them, i.e., orthogonal to $W$.] Then: If $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is a basis for $W^\perp$, i.e., for the nullspace of $A$, then $W$ is given precisely by the equations $v_1\cdot x = v_2\cdot x = \dots = v_k\cdot x = 0$. (The fancy way of writing this is to say that $W=(W^\perp)^\perp$.)

[It might help to watch Lecture 38 — or perhaps more — of [these lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7BK3hg_qQs&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd).]